Using the Definition of the Riemann Integral to Calculate Area of Semi-Circle
I was hoping for some assistance in calculating the area of a unit semi-circle with the definition of the Riemann Integral. Using the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1-x^2}$, with end points $x=1, x=-1,$ I get the following:
$$\Delta x=\frac{2}{n}, x_i=-1+\frac{2}{n}i$$
$$A_c=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{1-(-1+\frac{2}{n}i)^2}\frac{2}{n}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sqrt{\frac{4}{n}i-\frac{4}{n^2}i^2}\frac{2}{n}$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{2}{n^2}\sqrt{i(n-i)}$$
From here, I am unsure how to approach the sum. Writing out the terms
$$\sqrt{n-1} + \sqrt{2n-4}+\sqrt{3n-6}+...$$
Hasn't done much in terms of recognizing an approach to the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Using the change of variable $x = \sin t$ in the integral, you see that $\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx = \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \cos^2 t \,dt$. For the second integral, all Riemann sums for $x_i = -\frac{\pi}{2}+ \frac{i \pi}{n}$ yield the exact result.
But maybe you are not allowed to use changes of variable at this point...
